# Finding point on line that lies a minimum distance from other point not on line Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy, scipy-optimize

I have used `scipy.optimize.fmin_cobyla` to find the minimum distance between a point and a line on a graph. Is there a way to get `fmin_cobyla` to return the point on the line (not the distance!) at which that minimum distance occurs? Currently, this is my code:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit, fmin_cobyla

P = (0.5, 2)

def logifunc(x,A,x0,k):
    return A / (1 + np.exp(-k*(x-x0)))


x, y = ecdf_xy(gene='Cd44', cluster_num=6, group='TREAT')
x[0] = 0

popt, pcov = curve_fit(logifunc, x, y, p0=[min(y), np.median(y), max(y)])

def f(x):
    return logifunc(x, *popt)

def objective(X):
    x,y = X
    return np.sqrt((x - P[0])**2 + (y - P[1])**2)

def c1(X):
    x,y = X
    return f(x) - y

X = fmin_cobyla(objective, x0=[0.5,0.5], cons=[c1])
print('The minimum distance is {0:1.2f}'.format(objective(X)))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.scatter(x, logifunc(x, *popt))
plt.plot(x, logifunc(x, *popt))
plt.plot(P[0], P[1], marker='o')

circle = plt.Circle(P, objective(X))
ax.add_patch(circle)
```

[image]

If there isn't a way to use `fmin_cobyla` to do this, how else might I find the point on the line that lies the minimum distance from P? That is the main goal of my question.

Any other comments or suggestions about my code are of course welcome.

Comment: If the input is actually a polyline and you care about only one point (per polyline), the fastest thing is to just check every segment.  For multiple query points, you can build a space-partitioning tree to quickly identify likely closest segments.

Comment: The `fmin_cobyla` method returns the found minimizer (the point) by default, so `X` already contains your point. That being said, you don't need to solve this as a constrained optimization problem. By plugging your constraint into the objective, it becomes an unconstrained optimization problem.